# angular route getting problems

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

i'm trying to use ngRoute to config my routes on my app but for some reason, it still not working. i've searched a lot and seems my code is ok. i'm gonna show how i'm doing it:

**my a.href:**

```
<a href="#/bancodedados">
```

**my config route:**

```
    academico.config(function($routeProvider){


    var home = {
        controller : "home",
        templateUrl : "js/plugins/angular/views/home.html"
    }

    var bancodedados = {
        controller : "bancodedados",
        templateUrl : "js/plugins/angular/views/bancodedados.html"
    }

    $routeProvider
    .when("/", home)
    .when("/bancodedados", bancodedados);
});
```

but for some reason the app redirect me to *http://localhost/joli/#!/#%2Fbancodedados*

and still on the same views.

Comment: Can you share your html + full js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often because of upgrading angular to version 1.6 which changes the default hash prefix to `!` whereas it used to be `''` (the empty string). You can read more on this [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15496) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8).

**Potential Fix 1: Change your links to use `#!` (hashbang)** as follows:

```
<a href="#!/bancodedados">
```

**Potential Fix 2: reset the hash prefix back to the empty string** by injecting `$locationProvider` into your config block and then setting the hash prefix as follows:

```
academico.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    // The rest of your config block...
});
```